# Think Python metathesis pairs, help to understand solution

Tags: python, dictionary

I am learning python from the book Think Python, and there is an exercise I do not understand the solution to. The exercise is as follows:

Two words form a “metathesis pair” if you can transform one into the other by swapping two letters; for example, “converse” and “conserve”. Write a program that finds all of the metathesis pairs in the dictionary. Hint: don’t test all pairs of words, and don’t test all possible swaps.

Here is the code from the solution given in the book (or the link to the github if you prefer, https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkPython2/blob/master/code/metathesis.py):

```
def all_anagrams(filename):
    d = {}
    for line in open(filename):
        word = line.strip().lower()
        t = signiture(word)
        if t not in d:
            d[t] = [word]
        else:
            d[t].append(word)
    return d

def metathesis_pairs(d):
    """Print all pairs of words that differ by swapping two letters.
    d: map from word to list of anagrams
    """
    for anagrams in d.values():
        for word1 in anagrams:
            for word2 in anagrams:
                if word1 < word2 and word_distance(word1, word2) == 2:
                    print(word1, word2)


def word_distance(word1, word2):
    """Computes the number of differences between two words.
    word1, word2: strings
    Returns: integer
    """
    assert len(word1) == len(word2)

    count = 0
    for c1, c2 in zip(word1, word2):
        if c1 != c2:
            count += 1

    return count
```

I am struggling to understand what is happening in this part of the code:

```
for anagrams in d.values():
            for word1 in anagrams:
                for word2 in anagrams:
                    if word1 < word2 and word_distance(word1, word2) == 2:
                        print(word1, word2)
```

Does writing for word1 in anagrams, then for word2 in anagrams just make the programme pick the first and second words? And in the word list provided some of the words have more than two anagrams, does this programme just ignore that? The next part I don't understand is why why word1 < word2 is there at all, I don't understand why that would be a condition for this problem.

Sorry if my questions don't really make sense, I'm just really confused. Hopefully someone can help me understand, thanks a lot for reading.

Comment: `word1 < word2` is there because otherwise each pair would be listed twice (in both possible orders).

Comment: Ok yeah that makes sense, thanks. What about the two for statements, can you help me understand them?

Comment: `word1` goes through every string in the list `anagrams`, and `word2` also goes through every string in list `anagrams`, so in combination you get every pair of strings. It's a Cartesian product, if that helps.

Comment: Oh, and `word1 < word2` also avoids the case where `word1` and `word2` are the same string.

Comment: So do they both start at index 0 in the list or does word1 start at 0 and word2 at 1. Because wouldn't you just always be comparing the same word against itself otherwise?

Comment: Both loops give every word in the list. The `word1 < word2` check excludes the case where that gives you the same word twice.

Comment: Ok so are you effectively comparing the first word against every other word, then the second word, and so on? So like you loop over all the words in word2 before you do the next word in the word1 loop?

Comment: For what it's worth, the program is flawed. It only tests whether a pair of strings differ in two characters, but not actually whether those two characters are swapped. According to this 'abcdef' and 'abXdeY' would be a metathesis pair.

Comment: The programme assumes you are providing a dictionary with lists of anagrams as values, so your example wouldn't happen if you did that, but I suppose it is flawed in that there is nothing to stop someone not giving lists of anagrams and the programme would still say there were pairs.

Comment: @elliebartlett "Ok so are you effectively comparing the first word against every other word, then the second word, and so on?"—Yes

Comment: @khelwood Ok thanks a lot for your help, it still messes with my brain a bit to understand the actual flow of how that works, but I think I sort of get it.